# Is scroll bar included in the browser viewport width?

Tags: css

Wondering for CSS purposes if the scroll bar is included in the viewport width? Specifically I'm thinking about calculating the sizes for img srcset. For example, would I need to account for it by subtracting like this, where the 17px is the scroll bar:

```
sizes="(min-width: 38em) calc(50vw-17px), calc(100vw-17px)"
```

I mean it's not like 17px will make any difference in the image the browser picks, but just wondering.

Comment: Just to note, the width of the scrollbar is not necessarily the same for all users.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of desktop browsers the scrollbar isnt included in the viewport width, in mobile devices it is as the mobile device scrollbar isnt always there, only visible as a partially transparent interface. The viewport size is based on the area that the web page can actually be displayed in.